# Efficiently iterating through a database row (libpqxx), assigning values to a struct

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

I'm grabbing a row from a database using libpqxx and assigning the fields within the `pqxx::row` to a struct specifically designed to hold those values:

```
struct driveOperationRecord
{
    long int id = 0;
    long int drive_operator_id = 0;
    long int operator_operation_index = 0;
    long int specific_operation_id = 0;
    bool operation_outcome = false;
    std::string error_code = "";
    long int operation_seconds = 0;
    std::string operation_date = "";
    std::string serial_number = "";
    std::string model = "";
    long long int size = 0;
    std::string firmware = "";
};
```

To do this I'm currently using the following code:

```
void driveOperationEntryToRecord(pqxx::row entry, driveOperationRecord& record)
{
    try
    {
        if (!entry["id"].is_null()) record.id = entry["id"].as<int>();
        if (!entry["drive_operator_id"].is_null()) record.drive_operator_id = entry["drive_operator_id"].as<int>();
        if (!entry["operator_operation_index"].is_null()) record.operator_operation_index = entry["operator_operation_index"].as<int>();
        if (!entry["specific_operation_id"].is_null()) record.specific_operation_id = entry["specific_operation_id"].as<int>();
        if (!entry["operation_outcome"].is_null()) record.operation_outcome = entry["operation_outcome"].as<bool>();
        if (!entry["error_code"].is_null()) record.error_code = entry["error_code"].as<std::string>();
        if (!entry["operation_seconds"].is_null()) record.operation_seconds = entry["operation_seconds"].as<long int>();
        if (!entry["operation_date"].is_null()) record.operation_date = entry["operation_date"].as<std::string>();
        if (!entry["serial_number"].is_null()) record.serial_number = entry["serial_number"].as<std::string>();
        if (!entry["model"].is_null()) record.model = entry["model"].as<std::string>();
        if (!entry["size"].is_null()) record.size = entry["size"].as<long long int>();
        if (!entry["firmware"].is_null()) record.firmware = entry["firmware"].as<std::string>();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Which is absolutely horrible and I hate it. I've thought about using a switch with an appropriate enum but iterating through a switch 12 times feels even worse. Ideally I'd be able to use something like:

```
for (auto field : entry)
{
    if (!field.is_null()) record.<if only i could dynamically reference using field.name()> = field.as<somehow magically find appropriate type>();
}
```

But these things are impossible. Any ideas?

**EDIT** (In response to Useless):

The current database contains roughly 4,000 entries which will need to pass through this function on a fairly regular basis. It is expected to grow exponentially from here. In order to future proof, operational efficiency is also important. I am fairly new to c++ and I know that there is a lot that I don't know! I was just really hoping to find something slightly more elegant and have really been struggling to do so.

Comment: When you say "efficiently", what do you really need? The body of the question is about _programmer_ efficiency. Do you have any other constraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (auto field : entry)
{
    if (!field.is_null()) record.<if only i could dynamically reference using field.name()> = field.as<somehow magically find appropriate type>();
}
```

This is entirely feasible, although not quite like this.

Let's just assume we can have some record of what fields `driveOperationRecord` (henceforth just `Record`, for brevity) supports, along with their names, and types, and which data member they correspond to.  Then we can walk over them, like:

```
for (auto& field : record_fields)
{
  field.assign(row, record);
}
```

Now we need some field-describing type like

```
struct FieldDescriptor
{
  std::string name_;

  void assign(pqxx::row const& row, Record& record)
  {
    auto entry = row[name_];
    if (!entry.is_null()) {
      // do something
    }
  }
};
```

So far so good. The "do something" step is where we need to use something like virtual dispatch, because we're handling different types.

We *could* enumerate all the types we care about and write a big switch statement, but it's tedious. I'd start with the simplest thing first, and do something more complex if it turns out you really need it to be faster:

```
struct FieldDescriptor
{
  std::string name_;
  std::function<void(pqxx::field const&, Record&)> assign_;

  void assign(pqxx::row const& row, Record& record)
  {
    auto entry = row[name_];
    if (!entry.is_null()) {
      assign_(entry, record);
    }
  }
};
```

OK, so now we just need some way to build a function or callable object similar to

```
void assignFieldName(pqxx::field const& entry, Record& record) {
    record.fieldName = entry.as<decltype(record.fieldName)>();
}
```

For example, we could write

```
template <typename RecordType, typename FieldType>
FieldDescriptor describe(const char *name, FieldType RecordType::*member)
{
    return
    { std::string{name},
      [=member](pqxx::field const& entry, Record& record)
      {
        record.*member = entry.as<FieldType>();
      }
    };
}
```

and even wrap it up in a macro to save a little more typing:

```
#define DESCRIBE_RECORD_FIELD(F) describe(#F, &Record:: F)

FieldDescriptor record_fields[] = {
    DESCRIBE_RECORD_FIELD(id),
    DESCRIBE_RECORD_FIELD(drive_operator_id),
    DESCRIBE_RECORD_FIELD(operator_operation_index),
    DESCRIBE_RECORD_FIELD(specific_operation_id),
    DESCRIBE_RECORD_FIELD(operation_outcome),
    DESCRIBE_RECORD_FIELD(error_code),
    DESCRIBE_RECORD_FIELD(operation_seconds),
    DESCRIBE_RECORD_FIELD(operation_date),
    DESCRIBE_RECORD_FIELD(serial_number),
    DESCRIBE_RECORD_FIELD(model),
    DESCRIBE_RECORD_FIELD(size),
    DESCRIBE_RECORD_FIELD(firmware)
};
```

Now, we have sort of shadowed the whole definition of `Record` again, which is unfortunate. It's possible to avoid this ... but only by replacing the whole definition with a bunch of macros that do double duty declaring the members, and registering their descriptors.

For a small number of records, I'd probably stick with what we have here. If there are a lot, it's worth making more effort to automate (and to make sure the definition can't get out of sync with the registered descriptors).

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, you can always go old school to avoid tedious and error prone repetition:

```
#define ENTRY_TO_RECORD(TYPE) \
  {
    auto e = entry[#NAME]; \
    if (!e.is_null()) {\
      record.NAME = e.as<decltype(NAME)>(); \
    } \
  }

void driveOperationEntryToRecord(pqxx::row entry, driveOperationRecord& record)
{
    try
    {
        ENTRY_TO_RECORD(id);
        ENTRY_TO_RECORD(drive_operator_id);
        ENTRY_TO_RECORD(operator_operation_index);
        ENTRY_TO_RECORD(specific_operation_id);
        ENTRY_TO_RECORD(operation_outcome);
        ENTRY_TO_RECORD(error_code);
        ENTRY_TO_RECORD(operation_seconds);
        ENTRY_TO_RECORD(operation_date);
        ENTRY_TO_RECORD(serial_number);
        ENTRY_TO_RECORD(model);
        ENTRY_TO_RECORD(size);
        ENTRY_TO_RECORD(firmware);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Yeah, I know this is generally frowned upon, and I should say that there's all sorts of caveats with using precompiler macros (like, don't put them in your header files).

So probably just consider this a temporary workaround while someone comes back with a more idiomatic solution.

Comment: There isn't a _much_ more idiomatic solution, although you can avoid writing out the field type by using `decltype`. The only real concern is that it's hard to break out early when you get a match, so you're making a lot of redundant calls to `entry[#NAME]`

Comment: Good point. I wasn't sure whether there would always be a 1:1 between the type needed as the template argument and the struct type. I'll update my suggestion to use decltype though.

Comment: Also updated to avoid redundant calls to entry[#NAME].